# Why is going through getErrorStream() necessary to run a process?

Tags: java, process

I am executing a process using the Process class. Going through the error stream seems to be necessary to execute the process successfully. Why is going through the error stream necessary for the process to run correctly? Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
Process wkstdin = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedWriter wkstdin_writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(wkstdin.getOutputStream()));
//write data
```

Necessary Part of the Code:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            wkstdin.getErrorStream()));
String ch;
while ((ch = input.readLine()) != null)
{
  System.out.println(ch);
}
```

Comment: Oh did not notice that, will do @skynorth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the process writes to stderr the output goes to a fixed-size buffer. If the buffer fills up then the process blocks until there is room for the remaining output in the buffer. So if the buffer doesn't empty then the process will hang.

Also if something goes wrong with the process you'd like to know about it, the error stream may contain actual useful information.

Some suggestions:

- Naming a String ch seems misleading, since ch is usually used for chars.
- I like to put the code that reads from stderr in a dedicated worker thread. That way switching between reading the input stream and the error stream happens automatically without my having to allow for it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! So I realized this also does not work when I use `getInputStream()` instead of `getErrorStream()`. Is this also dependent on the process and what stream it uses to output its data?

Comment: @Ryan: the convention is for programs to write their normal output to stdout and write error-diagnostic information to stderr. so you need to read from both of them.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the target process you are executing.

Many a times the target process will **block** until the streams are consumed(**the target process's stream buffers need to be drained**). So if you are not processing the error/output streams then the target process may appear to be hung as its blocked for the the stream to be drained.

Comment: The target process doesn't actively wait.  Rather, it attempts to write to its stdout or stderr, and is **blocked** because the buffer / pipe connecting the process to your code is full.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying suraj and stephen.